# Why my custom typescript alias is not working?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mern, tsconfig

I am creating a `MERN Stack` college project so i am using `typescript` in backend.

In `tsconfig.json` i am using some custom alias for file navigation.

my `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "@controllers/*": ["./src/controllers/*"],
      "@models/*": ["./src/models/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["./src/routes/*"],
      "@customTypes/*": ["./src/customTypes/*"],
      "@databases/*": ["./src/databases/*"],
      "@functions/*": ["./src/functions/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["./src/middlewares/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**but after i start the development server this error occur:**

```
[INFO] 00:06:56 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.1, typescript ver. 5.1.6)
Error: Cannot find module '@routes/login'
Require stack:
- D:\Projects\sd-college\server\src\index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\sd-college\server\src\index.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._compile (D:\Projects\sd-college\server\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\KANNUM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-17848745239557018.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (C:\Users\KANNUM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-17848745239557018.js:114:20)
[ERROR] 00:06:57 Error: Cannot find module '@routes/login'
Require stack:
- D:\Projects\sd-college\server\src\index.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { authStudentRoute } from "@routes/login";
dotenv.config();

const app: Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Build Folder Need To Be Served!");
});
app.use(authStudentRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am just try to expect that it should be recognized by the typescript of my custom alias.

Comment: Sometimes, restarting your dev server makes it work. Did you try it?

Comment: i just restart my whole pc but didn't work

Comment: The function of `"paths"` is to instruct TypeScript that the specified mappings will be available at runtime. It is not make them available. The primary usecase is to describe loader or bundler configuration such as example as SystemJS's map, Webpack's alias, or RequireJS's paths. See the docs for [Path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@controllers/*": ["src/controllers/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "@customTypes/*": ["src/customTypes/*"],
      "@databases/*": ["src/databases/*"],
      "@functions/*": ["src/functions/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["src/middlewares/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

In `package.json` :

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "ts-node index.ts",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `ts-node` to start your server. According to the  [ts-node website](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/paths), `tsconfig-paths` must be installed to use the `paths` in `tsconfig.json`

Install `tsconfig-paths` as a dev dependency:

```
npm install tsconfig-path --save-dev
```

Add `ts-node` to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {...},
  "exclude": [...],
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Same Issue

Comment: @KannuMandora What happens if you use the relative path like this: `import { authStudentRoute } from "./routes/login";`